# Possible to format the raw image file (.iso or .img) to FAT / NTFS / exFAT in Windows?

Tags: windows

Would it be possible to format the raw image file (.iso or .img) to one of the following formats

- FAT;
- exFAT;
- NTFS
  in Windows?

If so, how?

(Preferably, FAT & exFAT).

Thanks for your reply.

Additional information:

- the mounted image file can only be formatted to UDF in Disk Management in Windows;
- the mounted image was previously “fsck"ed and "e2fsck"ed in Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: To format the mounted raw image file.

Comment: That's not the problem, it's what you think is a solution for something, the very definition of a X-Y problem. What is this ISO file and/or does it come from? What the purpose of mounting it and why do you think it needs format?

Comment: Is it related to your other (closed) question? https://superuser.com/questions/1768353/how-to-check-and-repair-corrupted-iso-image If so then please understand 1. You may try correcting logical errors on file systems and *hope* that'll fix the files; 2. Unlike multimedia files that may be somewhat useable if when "broke" - garbled images, missing/skipped frames, etc. any container type file MUST be recovered to a pristine condition or it won't work/mount, etc. **You're looking for a solution to something that very likely has none**, end of the story.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, it's perfectly possible to format a Mac .dmg file to any of the above, also HFS or APFS… but it still won't get you anywhere because what you appear to have is an already-corrupt ISO container. Copying that to a 'new disk' image won't fix it, just the same as copying it to a USB stick or another computer won't fix it.

Comment: From your screenshot you are not manipulating an image, but a writable DVD inside an optical drive. If that is a result of any kind of emulation, you should start looking for approaches that does NOT involve such emulation. If that is not, you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: This is making less and less sense. First of all, "mounted" with what? Daemon Tools or alike? Or is this some Windows VM hosted on Linux (i.e. the image file resides on the host side and is attached to the VM)? And why did you even mention (e2)fsck when it's seemingly entirely irrelevant? (It makes no sense to e2fsck unless it's an ext2/3/4 image and it makes no sense to format an image file that was already formatted, since one can simply create a new blank image anyway.)

Comment: It is an ext4 image, mate.

Comment: @TomYan It is highly likely OP named the image `.iso` and Windows ended up mounting it in a virtual optical drive (as natively supported). Makes a lot of sense for me, even though it will not help achieve the original goal.

Comment: Nope. It was mounted by ImDisk as a local disk, which enabled it to be formatted to FAT in Disk Management in Windows. Virtual Clone Drive, WinCDEmu, OSFMount, and many others either found the raw image corrupted, quit midway or could only mount it as read-only CD Rom. I'm still testing other mounting and burning tools, if you have other recommendations, it would be most welcome.

Comment: The ultimate goal of this thread was to format the raw image, whether by means of repairing it or mounting it by some third-party tool. PS: In Ubuntu, the same image file was proved to be corrupted, and only able to be mounted (as read-only) after fsck and e2fsck. But in Windows, it was mounted straight away by ImDisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. However, Windows cannot do it by itself. You need third-party software to make Windows see the image as a virtual disk drive. You can then proceed formatting it as you would a normal hard drive.

[OSFMount](https://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) is one such software. [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) is yet another excellent program for this. Both can also act as RAM disks.

Keep in mind that the `.iso` extension is “reserved” for images of optical media and generally treated as read-only storage. If you do want to create an ISO image, you need specialized software for that. Unfortunately, again, Windows does not ship with that. [ImgBurn](https://www.imgburn.com/) is an excellent freeware utility that does the job. More advanced editing might require other tools.

Windows also offers native support for the VHD and VHDX image formats.

Comment: Thanks for the software recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Negative answer :
[Optical disc image (ISO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_image)
is defined as:

> An optical disc image (or ISO image, from the ISO 9660 file system used with CD-ROM media) is a disk image that contains everything that would be written to an optical disc, disk sector by disc sector, including the optical disc file system. ISO images are expected to contain the binary image of an optical media file system (usually ISO 9660 and its extensions or UDF), including the data in its files in binary format, copied exactly as they were stored on the disc. The data inside the ISO image will be structured according to the file system that was used on the optical disc from which it was created.

The ISO file format is defined by the
[ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660),
so does not use disk formats such as FAT, exFAT or NTFS.

You may use disk imaging products to image disks in those
formats to backup files, but these would be files of
proprietary formats that cannot be understood as ISO.

Comment: Pertinent edit. I was about to comment just that to suggest an improvement to the question but you were faster :) Anyway, even if possible a question about "formatting an image file", whatever it might be, is nonsensical. This seems to be a X-Y problem.

Comment: The answer was beside the point, and did not solve the issue - format the mounted raw image file to one of the 3 formats.

Comment: The answer IS on point: It can't be done (and makes no sense). I suggest you ask about the problem you're trying to solve not about what you think is a solution and clearly isn't.

Comment: The point is that this is impossible. If you wish to take a backup image of a disk, use suitable products such as AOMEI, EaseUS etc.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - in the 1990s when computers were not widely used, the crime writer Patricia Cornwell gave her character "Kay Scarpetta" a PC in one of her books. She wrote that Kay switched it on, and among other things, 'formatted a few files". Her young niece, a "geek", suggested she try "Unix", because "it's a great program".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey LMAO... And suddenly the old Ena Pá 2000 - Portuguese parody multi-genre band - song which includes 5the line *"please send me the PDF so I can open the file"* seems mundane and plausible (the PDF could've contained instructions or a password to a protected file).